# adding master1 and master2 to load balancer in implementing HA kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I am exploring the implementation of CI/CD pipeline using kubernetes and jenkins. I am planned to use multi master kubernetes cluster - HA cluster. And using the etcd cluster on the master nodes. I am following the below tutorial for learning,

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/

Here when I am reading I found that - After Run kubeadm init on master1 and master2, there is a step "**Add master1 and master2 to load balancer**".

Actually  I am confused in this step that , Do I need to use another VM as a load balancer ? Or master0 master1 and master2 setup defaultly giving one load balancer ?

I am not clear about this step about load balancer in HA kubernetes cluster. Can anyone clarify my confusions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you have to create Load Balancer for masters and add other masters to LB pool manually.

Here is a part from the "[Building High-Availability Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/building/)" document, "Replicating API Servers" section:

> **Load balancing**
>   At this point, you should have 3 apiservers all working correctly. If you set up a network load balancer, you should
>   be able to access your cluster via that load balancer, and see traffic
>   balancing between the apiserver instances. Setting up a load balancer
>   will depend on the specifics of your platform, for example
>   instructions for the Google Cloud Platform can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/).
>
> Note, if you are using authentication, you may need to regenerate your
>   certificate to include the IP address of the balancer, in addition to
>   the IP addresses of the individual nodes.
>
> For pods that you deploy into the cluster, the kubernetes service/dns
>   name should provide a load balanced endpoint for the master
>   automatically.
>
> For external users of the API (e.g. the kubectl command line
>   interface, continuous build pipelines, or other clients) you will want
>   to configure them to talk to the external load balancer’s IP address.

Please also find two parts, related to **Cloud load balancer** and **On Site load balancer** in the [Creating HA clusters with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/) document.
(It's hidden above "Acquire etcd cert") in "Choose one.../Cloud/On-Site" section.